# Modificar contenido desde un DataGridView y validar actualizacion

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, windows-forms, datagrid

Estoy trabajando dentro de C# con Windows Forms, desarrollo una aplicación donde los registros de la DataGriedView se cargan desde la base datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi cuestión es como puedo editar los registros desde el datagriedview y al mismo tiempo a dar enter validar la actualización y los registros se queden guardados tanto en el DataGridView así como en la base de datos.

Saludos.

Comment: Lee sobre eventos con el keypress podes hacer lo segundo. Con lo primero, no sé si tenes bloqueadas las celdas. Pero también podes revisar eventos, para habilitarla al dar doble clic. Lee sobre eso. Son mis sugerencias. Proba y si seguis teniendo problemas adjunta el código.

Comment: Buen dia @AlexVarela probe con CellandEdit eso los deja guardados en forma de DataGridView mas no en la base datos, tienes algun ejemplo de como seria el query para poder actualizar.